# Magento 2.2.1 change checkout component sort order

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.2.1

I added new checkout step using [official doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) , i need to display my step in between shipping and payment.
As per the documentation `To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2` so I have added following code 
 *checkout_index_index.xml*

```
<item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amsi_UserManagement/js/view/select-student-view</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    </item>
</item>
```

*Amsi_UserManagement/view/frontend/web/js/view/select-student-view.js*

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();
    stepNavigator.registerStep(
        'select_student_step',
        null,
        'Select Student',
        this.isVisible,
        _.bind(this.navigate, this),
        15
    );

    return this;
}
```

this creates my steps like this

[image]

when I click **`NEXT`** in shipping method it directly taking me to the payment page, that is weird. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

To avoid mixed steps views, I just changed this:

```
isVisible: ko.observable(true)
```

For this:

```
isVisible: ko.observable(false)
```

#### **Edit**

My step is coming in between shipping and payment step, so while the cart item is virtual both select-student and payment will be active at the same time. To overcome that i need to over write the logic of `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment`. So I extended  it using `view/base/requirejs-config.js` file

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment':
                'Amsi_UserManagement/js/view/payment'
        }
    }
};
```

in new payment.js file I added

```
isVisible: checkVisible(),

function checkVisible() {
   if(quote.isVirtual() && !stepNavigator.stepCodes.length)
       return ko.observable(true);
  else
      return ko.observable(false);
 }
```

also I changed my-step

```
isVisible: checkVisible(),
    function checkVisible() {
        if(quote.isVirtual() && !stepNavigator.stepCodes.length)
            return ko.observable(true);
        else
            return ko.observable(false);
    }
```